# How to join 2 hive tables by point and corresponding polygon?

Tags: hadoop, hive, gis, hiveql

I have 2 Hive tables. Table 1 have longitudes and latitudes in 2 columns and 2nd table have polygon information in WKT format like bellow:

```
POLYGON ((6.93614 79.842882, 6.950198 79.856958, 6.943638 79.877815, 6.931795 79.877129, 6.92566 79.861507, 6.919184 79.861507, 6.917906 79.847603, 6.93614 79.842882))
```

I want to find out which points in the table 1 belong to which polygons.I'm trying to use ST_Geometric library for hadoop (https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Documentation) to do this. Since data in 2 tables i have to join them. I try to use

```
ST_Contains(polygon, point)
```

function to join 2 tables. But I couldn't do it. Do some one know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[`ST_Contains`](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Relationships#st_contains) runs on a single polygon and a single point, not full tables.

You need to do a full cartesian product join (an inner join with no conditions) and then apply the `ST_Contains` in the where clause:

```
 select * from polygonTable a,pointsTable b where ST_Contains(a.polygon,b.point);
```

Note that doing a cartesian product is inefficient and may take a lot of time on big tables.

Comment: If the table is big and you need to avoid the cartesian product, it is possible to write a custom map-reduce query with a quadtree index, instead of a Hive query - https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples/point-in-polygon-aggregation-mr

Comment: Yes the problem is  cartesian product. I use CROSS JOIN. Do you know any beginner friendly document about  custom map-reduce query?